# How to mark a flag on parent child hierarchy from Next process in SQL or Powerbi

Tags: sql, powerbi, parent-child

I have parent child hierarchy for production materials. This is in below format:

[image]

Parent ID and Child ID are yet not present, but I can plan for that.
Now any of these parent/child product can go for next process, say Baking. This Process is such that, once done, all consecutive child's of the product under Baking should be marked with the baking unique code.

Say, Baking is done for these 2 products, A and Q and Baking unique code B1 and B2 are generated in this table:

[image]

Then I would like to have the result as below:
[image]

I have tried to self join and like things in SQL/Power BI after lot of Google, but could not achieve that.

I will prefer the solution in SQL or Power Bi. Certainly it is preferred to get it done in Source, but its acceptable in either of these, whichever can be more efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify this question? First of all what is the table header of the two row, two column table. Second, please clarify the IDs B1 and B2 - do both mean that the product A and the product B were baked, why those Products are not both marked as B1?

Comment: 1. First column is name of product which may be parent or child anyone. Second column is the baking ID, it is just random unique code.

Comment: 2. Product A and Q were baked and provided baking ID code B1 and B2.

Comment: @SevenOfNine Hope I have clarified your questions, I also edited my original question. Can you please devote some time on this question. Thanks for help.